# Char array at an int in C18

Tags: pic, c, software, mplab, c18

In Jal, it's possible to do something like this:

```
var word the_var = 0x1234
var byte the_array[2] at the_var;
```

Now you can easily access the bytes of the word `the_var` with `the_array[0]` (`0x34`) and `the_array[1]` (`0x12`). Can something similar be done with the C18 compiler?

I have an `unsigned int the_var` and want to access the separate `char`s in that variable using an array.

Comment: Is a [C union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) what you're after?

Comment: @MikeJ-UK would that be possible with a char _array_ as well? If so, could you give me a basic usage example (in an answer)?

Comment: I think PeterJ beat me to it!

Comment: @MikeJ-UK that's too bad, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One C equivalent is to use a anonymous union, there are a few ways to use them so it's worth researching them further but an example is:

```
static union {
  word the_var;
  byte the_array[2];
};
the_var = 0x1234;
some_value = the_array[0];
some_other_value = the_array[1];
```

Another way to go about it is to use a pointer to the value:

```
word the_var = 0x1234;
byte *the_array = (byte *) &the_var;
some_value = the_array[0];
some_other_value = the_array[1];
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just a note: the `byte *the_array = &thevar;` assignment will not compile in C++.

Answer (score 3):

In C, you can always get a pointer to the data structure and cast it to some other type (such as `uint8_t`, like this:

```
long myLong = 123456;
uint8_t* bytePtr = (uint8_t*)(&myLong);
uint8_t seventByte = bytePtr[6];
```

The first line is your non-byte data, of type `long` in this case. The second line declares a byte pointer (essentially the same as an array in C) to the same data by taking the address of the data, casting it to a `uint8_t` pointer, and assigning that to `bytePtr` which is a pointer to byte(s). The third line exploits the fact that pointers and arrays are almost the same thing in C and treats our `bytePtr` as an array, so we get the seventh byte out of it via the bracked notation.